# Event ID 8888 - SharePoint Services 4.0 cannot be found

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

By this morning 2 of my SharePoint 2016 servers throwing following errors every minute in Event log. Any idea what it is.

The description for Event ID 8888 from source Windows SharePoint Services 4.0 cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

Deadlock detected with GCriticalSection in process 19148, return code 258

Comment: Got the same error happening all of a sudden (was fine for months before), did you find out the cause ?